# How to compute taylor series $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ about $a=3$?

Tags: calculus, functions, summation, taylor-expansion

How to compute taylor series $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$ about $a=3$? It should be associated with the geometric series. Setting $t=x-3,\ x=t+3$, then I don't know how to continue, could someone clarify the procedure?

Comment: do not sweat: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+1%2F(1-x)+at+x%3D3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac 1 {1-x} = \frac 1 {1-(t+3)} = \underbrace{\frac{-1/2}{1-(-t/2)} = \frac{-1}2 \left( 1 - \frac t 2 + \frac{t^2} 4 - \frac{t^3} 8 + \cdots \right)}_\text{a geometric series} 
$$

Comment: Just wondering how did you achieve $ \frac {1}{1-(t+3)} = \frac{-1/2}{1-(-t/2)} $?

Comment: @fff : $$ \frac 1 {1-(t+3)} = \frac 1 {-2-t} = \frac{-1/2}{1+(t/2)} = \frac 1 {1-(-t/2)}. $$

Answer (score 2):

The formula of Taylor series expansion is $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$, where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative. In this case $a=3$ and what you need to compute is the derivatives of $f$ and then to plug in $a=3$.

$f^{(n)}(x)=n!(1-x)^{-(n+1)}$, so $f^{(n)}(3)=n!(-2)^{-(n+1)}$. substituting this in the Taylor formula, we get $f(3)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x-3)^n(-2)^{-(n+1)}$.

Hopefully, I did not commit any computational error :)